# Python program wait and continue after action from UI

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've a python program which launches a browser. After the user performs certain action, I want the rest of the python program to execute from where it left off. I've set a button (stop) in the UI, which when clicked should continue to execute the rest of the python program.
How do I achieve this task? Any Python module that would help me on this?

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Comment: I'm able to launch the browser but after launch of browser, I'm unable to stop the python program there. I need to perform certain actions and then want to use STOP button from UI, to continue executing the remaining python program

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: 'code'                                                                                                          
PROXY = "test:8080" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY) # Connect Chrome to proxy
# Enter chromedriver path
chrome = webdriver.Chrome("<driver path>",chrome_options=chrome_options)
chrome.get(url)
--------------------------------------- I want to stop/pause the program for here --------------------------------
Remaining code to be executed later.
All these are written in a single function

Comment: Can you not separate the functions? One function starts the browser en the button executes another function. Are you using something like FLASK?